# How to download a file from the server using a POST request or a more secure method without using a GET request for iOS application.

Tags: ios, ios5, post, webserver, download

I do not want to use asihttp methods so is there a way to download a file from the server without having to use a get request? How to use a post request to download the file from the server?

Comment: What are you using for your server side code? PHP? Some more details would help in answering this question. To download a file from a server you can convert the file to a data string and then send that over HTTPS. iOS can then convert the string back to data. You can also do the same the other way. Convert to data on iOS side and then POST the file to the server.

Comment: I am using python and django for my server side.

Comment: What you need to do in your python web service is Fetch the file convert it to a string and send it to iOS. You could use a simple POST request from iOS to call your python web service. As long as iOS receives the data it can convert it back to whatever file format you need it to be in (of course needs to be supported by iOS if you want to use it). There are many posts and tutorials about this on Stackoverflow and other sources on the internet. I cannot help you with python and django but if you want I can show you how in PHP.

Comment: OK please show me.. thanks it will be useful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP wants the answer regardless, I will use PHP for this.

iOS client side:

```
NSString *phpURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/getFile.php", serverAddress];
NSURL *phpURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phpURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:phpURL];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"filePath=%@", filePath];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [post length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]:
```

For the PHP side:

```
<?php

$filePath = htmlspecialchars($_POST['filePath']);

$fileData = file_get_contents($filePath);

echo $fileData;

?>
```

This is very basic. Also for the iOS side you would want to wrap that entire request in a code block that is run asynchronously in the background. You could use GCD for that. Once you have the file as responseData in iOS you can save the file to the local container and then do many things with it.